# 1:1 entity mapping in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orchardcms

I'm wondering if its is possible to create 1:1 mapping in Orchard CMS where I would have PK on one entity and PFK on other entity as keys. Im quite aware how to do this in NHibernate, but its not qite clear to me if there is a way how to do this in Orchard. Should I perhaps extend `SchemaBuilder` used in `DataMigrationImpl`, but then I also need a way to override NHibernate convention based mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You can see this documentation [Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations in Orchad CMS](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations). I hope it will help you lot.

Comment: Of course I alredy looked at this but my 1:1 requires PFK and I wonder if that is possible. I Already modeled 1:n and n:n with orchard before without any problem...